# Golang slice inside struct is not appending new values, just keep the first value

Tags: go, slice

I have a code that need to add new values.
The objective is assimilate users and quotes, and for that I create a struct called "UserQuote".

```
type UserQuote struct {
        User        models.User
        QuoteNumbers []int
    }
```

Each user will have some quotes, but quote need to be assimilated to one user.
And i create some loops that get quotes and randomic assimilate for users that I was previously select. This users if a another type of struct, that is not important for my question, but you need to know about they are stored in a slice named usersThatBuySweepstakeNumbersBySweepstake.

```
for _, quote := range availableQuotes {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        randomIndex := rand.Intn(len(usersThatBuySweepstakeNumbersBySweepstake))
        selectedUser := usersThatBuySweepstakeNumbersBySweepstake[randomIndex]
        selectedUserIsInList := false
        for _, userQuote := range usersQuotes {
            if userQuote.User.ID == selectedUser.ID {
                userQuote.QuoteNumbers = append(userQuote.QuoteNumbers, quote)
                selectedUserIsInList = true
            }
        }

        if !selectedUserIsInList {
            usersQuotes = append(usersQuotes, UserQuote{
                User:        selectedUser,
                QuoteNumbers: []int{quote},
            })
        }
    }
```

If users has not quotes previsouly associated, he doesn't was inserted into array of structs UserQuote. In this case, he is inserted on follow code snippet (is a part of prev code snipped):

```
if !selectedUserIsInList {
            usersQuotes = append(usersQuotes, UserQuote{
                User:        selectedUser,
                QuoteNumbers: []int{quote},
            })
        }
```

As you can see, the "QuoteNumbers" array is initialized
But, if he is already inserted, the "QuoteNumbers" array inside struct should be append, and here we have a problem: are not appending! The code snipped

```
for _, userQuote := range usersQuotes {
            if userQuote.User.ID == selectedUser.ID {
                userQuote.QuoteNumbers = append(userQuote.QuoteNumbers, quote)
                selectedUserIsInList = true
            }
        }
```

The code are only inserting the first element of this slice "QuoteNumbers", and later doesn't append.

I was execute application with debug, and are sure about "append" is calledthan expected, but the slice just keep the first element that was inserted when "instance" of struct are created

The follow code snipped have all code snippeds up, but ordered together:

```
type UserQuote struct {
        User        models.User
        QuoteNumbers []int
    }
    usersQuotes := make([]UserQuote, 0)

    //TODO
    if len(usersThatBuySweepstakeNumbersBySweepstake) == 0 {

    }

    availableQuotes := GetAvailableSweepStakesNumbersNumbers(sweepStake.ID)
    if availableQuotes == nil || len(availableQuotes) == 0 {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(400, gin.H{
            "message": "Não há mais números disponíveis para este sorteio",
        })
    }

    //TODO
    for _, quote := range availableQuotes {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        randomIndex := rand.Intn(len(usersThatBuySweepstakeNumbersBySweepstake))
        selectedUser := usersThatBuySweepstakeNumbersBySweepstake[randomIndex]
        selectedUserIsInList := false
        for _, userQuote := range usersQuotes {
            if userQuote.User.ID == selectedUser.ID {
                userQuote.QuoteNumbers = append(userQuote.QuoteNumbers, quote)
                selectedUserIsInList = true
            }
        }

        if !selectedUserIsInList {
            usersQuotes = append(usersQuotes, UserQuote{
                User:        selectedUser,
                QuoteNumbers: []int{quote},
            })
        }
    }
```

What is wrong about my "append"?

Answer (score 0):

When `append`ing elements to `slice` using a `range` loop, you should update the slice element using the loop index instead of updating the local variable (in you case the `userQuote`):

```
for _, quote := range availableQuotes {
    // ...
    for i, userQuote := range usersQuotes {
        if userQuote.User.ID == selectedUser.ID {
            usersQuotes[i].QuoteNumbers = append(usersQuotes[i].QuoteNumbers, quote) // update the slice indexed object
            selectedUserIsInList = true
        }
    }

    if !selectedUserIsInList {
        usersQuotes = append(usersQuotes, UserQuote{
            User:        selectedUser,
            QuoteNumbers: []int{quote},
        })
    }
}
```